# Should tags be edited out from a question if they appear irrelevant?

Tags: support, tags, editing

See [Off Wi-Fi LED in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124917/off-wi-fi-led-in-ubuntu) for an example:

[image: Possibly unrelated tags]

While it's ideally better to ask posters if, in this case, *lubuntu* and *syslinux* are indeed relevant to the question, suppose posters doesn't respond or, even worse, come back?

If there's no clarity from posters, and other Ask Ubuntu users don't take action (and I too forget to come back to this question later), these tags will result in "false positives" for people who are monitoring, for example, the *lubuntu* tag.

I'm inclined to remove such tags when I first encounter them. If posters feels they're germane, they can simply add them back.

What is the correct course of action here?

Comment: When I remove irrelevant tags, I usually write in edit summary that why I removed them.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Currently, +10k users can "Edit tags inline" without entering the regular edit mode.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm about to hit 5k. Still a long way to go for 10k.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should absolutely remove irrelevant tags, wrong tags, add missing tags and anything else that makes the question better. Collaborative editing is a big part of the SE model and tags are not special.

So yes, please, correct any tagging issues you see!